# Jasmine: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I need to test an AngularJs service which loads the image from url. Here is my service:

```
/*global angular, Image*/
(function () {
  'use strict';
  function SourceLoader($q, $log) {

    /**
     * Load an image from url and return a promise which is resolved when image is loading is done.
     * It return the images object as resolved promise.
     * @param url source of the image
     * @returns {Promise} unresolved promise of image.
     */
    function loadImage(url) {
      var deferred = $q.defer(),
          image = new Image();
      image.onload = function () {
        deferred.resolve(image);
      };
      image.onerror = function (error) {
        $log.error('Error while loading image from url ' + url);
        $log.debug(error);
        deferred.reject(error);
      };
      image.src = url;
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    /**
     * Load images from and array of urls nd return the array of loaded images. The order of returned
     * images is same as the order of passed urls.
     * @param urls sources if images in array.
     * @returns {Promise} unresolved promise.
     */
    function loadImages(urls) {
      var count = 0, deferred = $q.defer(),
          images = [],
          callback = function (image, index) {
            images.insert(index, image);
            count += 1;
            if (count === urls.length) {
              //All images are loaded. High time to resolve promise.
              deferred.resolve(images);
            }
          };
      urls.forEach(function (url, index) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function () {
          callback(image, index);
        };
        image.onerror = function (event) {
          $log.error('Error while loading image from url ' + url);
          $log.debug(event);
          callback(event, index);
        };
        image.src = url;
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
      loadImage: loadImage,
      loadImages: loadImages
    };
  }

  var app = angular.module('myCanvasModule'),
      requires = [
        '$q',
        '$log',
        SourceLoader
      ];
  app.factory('SourceLoaderService', requires);
}());
```

I am using Karma with Jasmine to for test suits. My test suits is something like this:

```
/*global describe, TestUtils, beforeEach, it, module, inject, SourceLoaderServiceTestData, done, expect*/
(function () {
  'use strict';
  describe('myCanvasModule: Services: SourceLoaderService-->\n\t', function () {
    var SourceLoaderService, getTestData;

    getTestData = TestUtils.getTestData.bind(null, SourceLoaderServiceTestData);

    beforeEach(function () {
      module('myCanvasModule');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
      inject(function ($injector) {
        SourceLoaderService = $injector.get('SourceLoaderService');
      });
    });

    describe('SourceLoaderService.loadImage-->\n\t', function () {
      var testData;
      beforeEach(function () {
        testData = getTestData('loadImage');
      });

      it('should load the source and return the image as response', function (done) {
        var image;
        SourceLoaderService.loadImage(testData.validSource).then(function (response) {
          image = response;
          done();
          console.log('called');
        },function (error) {
          console.log('called', error);
          done();
        });
      });

    });

  });
}());
```

When I run the test suits I get:

**Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.**

I don't know what is going wrong. I am new to Karma and Jasmine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe use Promise.all as return statement in loadImages. Then you can skip your count book keeping.

Comment: sorry did not get you.

Comment: is your image source url valid?

Comment: yes. Even if I put any other url like https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/gp/20600002150126/C8tgB-KmLX8Sg_ohLeQdeTrp4Ob4o0zkIAvf7VJiLbhkikHJRc9rXD4hk2Lpd6y-Q0bD=h900 then is also shows up the same error

Answer (score 2):

To test any usage of the $q provider in AngularJS you'll have to cause a digest cycle to allow any Promises to be resolved under-the-hood. You should try the following:

```
it('should load the source and return the image as response', function (done) {
  var image;

  SourceLoaderService.loadImage(testData.validSource)
    .then(function (response) {
      // ... success check
    },function (error) {
      // ... error check
    });

  // Call apply for the above Promise to resolve
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

**Edit:**

In response to the comment, you'll also need to create the $scope variable as follows:

```
var SourceLoaderService, $scope;

beforeEach(function () {
  inject(function ($injector) {
    SourceLoaderService = $injector.get('SourceLoaderService');
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no scope anywhere the service but still you suggest so tried but I am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: I've added some information on how to defined an instance of the `$scope`.

Comment: I am doing the same thing.

Comment: Are you trying to load an image from a network resource, or an image locally?

You could try wrapping the `$scope.$apply()` in a `setTimeout` of between 500-3000 milliseconds to allow calls to the network time to return.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this and also able to run your test case successfully too. I am not sure why do you need done thingie there but below changes worked for me.

```
it('should load the source and return the image as response', function () {
  var image;
  sourceLoader.loadImage('https://s0.2mdn.net/viewad/5406241/6-jira-software_therapy-agile-tools_free-trial_static_728x90.png').then(function (response) {
    image = response;
    //setTimeout(done(), 60000);
    console.log('called');
  },function (error) {
    console.log('called', error);
    //done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Having an argument in your "`it`" function will cause the test to perform an async call.

```
it('should load the source and return the image as response', function () {
  var image;
  sourceLoader.loadImage(testData.validSource).then(function (response) {
    image = response;
    console.log('called');
  },function (error) {
    console.log('called', error);
  });
});
```

In order to use the "`done`" callback to test async calls, you should move some code to the "`beforeEach`" function. Here's a [link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html) for reference.

Comment: In my case I am not able to get which part I should move in beforeEach can you please explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that image load takes more time than default timeout interval.
Try something like this:
`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000`. 
It sets time to wait for `done()` call to 30 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Array.insert is just not a function. You can extend Array to have an insert function of course. But there is a much simpler way. Either just call images[:N] = image or just use `Promise.all`:

This will simplify your `loadImages` function a lot:

```
var loadImages = function() {
  var loadImagePromises = urls.map(function(url) {
    return loadImage(url)
  })
  return Promise.all(loadImagePromises)
}
```

Comment: I have created my own Array.prototye.insert. Anyways this reafctoring I can do any time. The concern is how can I test loadImage